# Access a Phonegap-created Database from the app Widget

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cordova

I have a Phonegap app which creates/open a database:

```
db = window.openDatabase("MyDB.db", "1.0", "MyDB", 656565);
```

Besides that, I created an Widget for this app and I need to access the same database the Phonegap App creates. However, I'm not sure how I do this, since:

```
mydb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("MyDB.db", null, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

does not do the trick, apparently it doesn't find the database properly, the following error occurs:

```
sqlite3_open_v2("MyDB.db", &handle, 2, NULL) failed
```

Does anyone know if something like this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Already solved it...the only way around was to use [SQLitePlugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)

Not a big difference after all.